# mailkit: how to get email alias when it's an Office365 account

Tags: email, office365, alias, mailkit

I have an alias for my O365 account -- alias@mycompany.com, which gets forwarded to the real account -- realaccount@mycompany.com.  If I send an email to this 0365 alias from a non O365 account (say gmail), MailKit (pop or imap .net core client) shows the alias in the header.  If I send an email to an alias from an O365 account, it does not show the alias in MailKit.  Instead, it gives the real account.  It shows no indication that the email was sent to alias@mycompany.com.  In the desktop Outlook client, you can view the alias in the headers of the email.  Where is that client getting this info?  Are there compressed headers I'm not seeing?  Do I need to buy a separate O365 account for each alias?  I'm not sure if this is a MailKit or an Office365 thing but the finger is pointing to O365 because it works when an email is sent from a gmail account.  Again, it does not happen with email accounts that are not Office365.  It only happens when we have an 0365 account sending email to an O365 alias.

BTW, this was asked here:  [MailKit: How to get the To email address when it is an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43881516/1794888) but it wasn't answered with a solution.  I tried adding a comment to the post but it said I don't have enough "reputation points".

Comment: I think you can submit an issue in the Mialkit issue list too:https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues

Comment: This issue is an O365 issue, the standard IMAP, POP3 and SMTP protocols (which is what MailKit implements) know nothing about aliases.